# Since Google reduces the value of links alongside nofollow links, what is an alternative?

Tags: google, pagerank, backlinks, ranking, nofollow

Since 2009, Google counts `nofollow` links also as outgoing links, and thus reduces the value of the other links. What are some alternatives to stop Google counting outside links from my page?

If I make links appear on my page source like this:

```
<span hrefs="http://link" rel="nofollow" link="true">Link Name</span>
```

and then in JavaScript replace **span** with **a** tag and replace **hrefs** with **href** for every span tag that has link="true".

Will this help?

Comment: Do you have a source for your claim? See also http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/rel-nofollow-seo-effect

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't use nofollow"? Google *does* recognise nofollow.

Comment: Source: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/pagerank-sculpting/ | Before it wasn't counting links on page that had nofollow at all, but now, it simply doesn't give that page PR, but it still devalues PR of other links on page...

Comment: @Shark Thanks, I understand now. I edited the title so it's hopefully clearer, although John's answer is still the correct one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it will not help. What you're doing is trying to serve up different content to Google then to your users. That's definitely against Google's terms of service and is a great way to get **banned**.

There's nothing wrong with outbound links. If you don't want a site to get credit for the link to their site if you are concerned it is spam or otherwise low quality nofollow is exactly what you want. If you're trying to hide these links because you think linking to other sites is bad then you're greatly misinformed. This is doubly so if you are doing it for the sake of PageRank. [Outbound links can be a postive ranking factor](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/pagerank-sculpting/). Plus linking to other sites is an important tool for search engines to determine what is quality content and what isn't. By breaking this sytem you're breaking web and making search worse for everybody.

Stop sweating the small stuff and start focusing on what matters : quality content. If you spent as much time creating good content as you did manipulating the search results or chasing PageRank you'd have a website that would rank well naturally.

Comment: Er, I thought the most common reason for using nofollow was to prevent spammers from being able to gain pagerank (and thus discourage spam by reducing the incentive) without totally disabling user-posted content.

Comment: Okay, my example on this page was too rough, but with using of javascript AJAX to display some social links at footer, or creating iframe with noindex, nofollow will remove it, will at least minimize other links PR losing level.

Answer (score 1):

To add on what @JohnConde said, focusing on creating a create site and content will result in incoming links, which beyond the traffic they produce, plays a larger role in your google ranking then the outbound links you have.