# lot of internal links to one not relevant internal page may distort google's opinion of site content?

Tags: seo, google, links

if I have a lot of pages talking about cars, and nearly any of them point to

```
/gray-cars.htm or /city-cars.htm
```

because they are the most sold ones... do you think that

```
/red-cars.htm and /super-cars.htm
```

will appear less important in google's opinion about the site, that talks about any type of car, not only the gray / city ones?

Comment: It might help if you explained in more detail what you want to accomplish.  Is it to rank higher when a user searches for "red cars"?  Or just to have `red-cars.html` show up before `gray-cars.htm` when the user searches for just "cars"?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. If you're linking to those other pages more you're in effect telling Google those pages are more important. And they are since you're selling more of them then the other ones.

Comment: thank you for the answer! rel="nofollow" will help? or it is better some javascript solution? thanks!

Comment: `rel=nofollow` [probably won't help](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27836): you can use it to reduce the rank of they gray/city cars pages, but that won't increase the rank of the red/super cars pages (except in a purely relative sense).

Comment: If your goal is to increase the ranking of the red cars pages, etc, get more incoming links from other websites to them.

Comment: my goal is get all pages at the same identical rank (internally)... then nofollow may help? thank you

Comment: `nofollow` will only reduce PR of pages gray-cars/city-cars page WITHOUT increasing PR of othe red-cars pages in your sie. According to Matt Cutts (Google's alter ego) links with `nofollow` do not save your PR to flow away, the PR flows but evaporates instead of being passed to other pages, read this: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/pagerank-sculpting

Comment: @MarcoDemaio hi, but what about internal links (links between pages on the same site) ?

Comment: It applies to **all** links